# Use Configmap Value in NodeSelectorTerms Entry

Tags: kubernetes, volume, configmap

The nodeSelectorTerms in a PersistentVolume help the volume identify which node to bind to. For example:

```
nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - mynodename
```

means that we only want to bind to a node of the name `mynodename`.

I would like to replace `mynodename` with a variable defined in a configMap. For example, the following syntax is what I was imagining, but it does not work:

```
nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: my-configmap
                key: MYNODENAME
```

where `my-configmap` is a configmap and `MYNODENAME` is a variable in it.

Can I achieve this somehow?

Comment: I don't think so, no. I'm not sure there's an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. Apparently I need more words than just that.